# Cannot boot into OS X after partitoning

Tags: startup, partition, recovery, dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu on a Mac Mini, everything works great. I'm able to switch back and forth without any problems. After that, I used GParted in Ubuntu to resize the OS X partition. I then create a FAT32 partition from a unallocated partition which was resized in previous step.

The result look like this:

[image: Partitions]

All of the procedures were done successfully without any errors, but after restart I cannot boot into OS X again, whereas the Ubuntu still alright. I tried to remove the FAT32 partition but still no positive.
How can I make OS X work again? (please don't hate me, I didn't make a backup since I don't have any significant data on OS X). I've been googling around and the solution seems to reinstall from Recovery. Is there any other ways other than reinstall?

Environment:
Mac Mini
Dual-boot: Mac OS X 10.11 and Ubuntu 14.04

Here's a little more partitions list:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

This command does not show the partition 5 and 6. I don't know why
[image: fsidk -l]

```
sudo lsblk -o /dev/sda
```

[image: lsblk-o]

All of above commands are executed in linux.

Comment: Have you tried removing the FAT32 partition and then booting up?

Comment: When you say to created the FAT32 partition, where did you create it?  When you boot into recovery, can you go into terminal and execute the command `diskutil list` and then paste the result to your question?  It helps to know what we are looking at.

Comment: Please add your system version and the output of `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` and `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` to your question!

Comment: @klanomath Thanks for reminding me. But I'm not with the Mac right now, I added a few details which I'm able to run on linux.